# Is it possible to access a Bluetooth characteristic without discovering it first?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-bluetooth

We are able to connect to our Bluetooth devices, but our services and characteristics are not discovered. Is it possible to use a characteristic that has not been discovered? I've tried creating a CBMutableCharacteristic and manually adding properties like the correct UUID to it, but does not seem to be accessible.

Before we spend too much time on this, does anyone know if it's possible to access a characteristic that has not been discovered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know is not possible.
Using `CoreBluetooth` you must read or write to a `CBCharacteristic` object and you can obtain one of them only discovering it for a specific service, using a specified `CBUUID` or get the full list of all the characteristic exposed by that service.